# how to show dynamic html code and call dynamic jquery on it as soon as it renders

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript

I am working on React Typescript application. where i am getting some html and its jQuery script from api call response. I want to render that html from component and want to call that jQuery script as soon as html renders. Here is the example.

html Code:

```
<div>
<div id="day">This is day div</div> 
<div id="night">This is night div</div>
<div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('#day').show();
$('#night').hide();
```

So when component loads, both div will be rendered but just after that jquery will run and hide the night div and only day div should be visible.

Comment: There are lots of ways to run a JavaScript function when the page is loaded, what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not pageload. i have single page application and i am loading one component on button click.

Comment: I started to answer your question with use document ready...but I can't pretend like i understand your question after reading your comment.

Comment: It's the same concept, you want to know when the DOM is 'ready'.  Like this.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650326/dom-ready-event-in-react/38650575

Comment: Also, why wouldn't you just render it hidden with CSS if you want it hidden?

Comment: I don't know much about react, but what you're looking for is state and life cycle specifically `componentDidMount()` : https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: you could use jQuery `.ajaxComplete` instead of `.ready`

Comment: above html and jQuery both are coming from api response. i have to insert that on my page. and have to call that jQuery as soon as html render.

Answer (score 0):

Declare some style tags with display none on the elements that you want to hide at begining (JQuery .show and .hide changes between display:block and display:none, so next calls to .show and .hide will work ok):

```
<div id="day" style="display:block;">This is day div</div> 
<div id="night" style="display:none;">This is night div</div>
```

If you want to do it with Javascript at all costs, then you can add a  tag (just) after the div blocks. If the  block is after the divs, then the divs will be available to modify for the Javascript code.

However maybe JQuery is not available yet, because JQuery is usually recomended to be loaded at the bottom of the page. You can change the JQuery loading position or you can use simple Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("day").style.display = "none";
```

Or you can also hide all your page contents until .ready is called.